# Excel FLOOR.MATH error when used with MATCH

Tags: excel

When I use the result of a `floor.math` function as input for a `match` function, the `match` function returns `#N/A` even when the result of `floor.math` is in the `match` array.

See below screenshots of my input. It seems that the `floor.math` function is not returning *exactly* 0.6, but I can't understand why.

This error does not occur with all results of `floor.math`. For example, using the function to round 0.85 down to 0.8 does not result in an error when the output is fed into `match`.

[image: decimal number is entered]

[image: floor.math is used to round the number down]

[image: match does not fiund the number, despite it being in the array]

Comment: `ROUNDDOWN` works. It's floating-point error.

Comment: In certain circumstance I need to be able to round a number down by a certain multiple, hence why I am using ```floor.math```. ```rounddown``` only rounds by multiples of 10, 1, 0.1 etc. For example, I use ```floor.math``` to round 0.78 down to the nearest multiple of 0.2, with the desired result being 0.6

Comment: Then `ROUND` after you've done the `FLOOR.MATH` to a certain number of significant digits. `=ROUND(FLOOR.MATH(B3,0.1),1)`. This is floating-point error at work